# python np array add dimension based on index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add a new dimension to an array based on another array.

For example, I have `array1` that have the shape `(12800,50)` and `array2` `(51283,49)`.

I want a final array that has the shape `(12800,50,49)`

```py
array1([[20004, 30643, 23090, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [14825, 20020, 19731, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [ 6813, 17206, 19915, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        ...,
        [14681, 26074, 12886, ..., 49652, 32971,     0],
        [28542,  9019,  9156, ...,     0,     0,     0],
        [18065,  5299, 10397, ...,     0,     0,     0]], dtype=int32)
```

IMPORTANT: each entity in `array1` represents the row of `array2`.

Does anyone have any clue how to achieve this using np, tf?

Comment: would this even be possible? array1.shape = (12800,50), array2.shape = (51283,49), array3.shape = (12800,50,49), are you gonna truncate array2? i.e., use the first 12800 rows in array2 only

Comment: I said in the IMPORTANT, select rows from array2 to add dim on array 1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It's simply array2[array1]. Hope this can help others in need